# Postfix doesn't send mail; example.com loops back to myself & Connection timed out

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

I have Postfix on Ubuntu 22.04. I can only receive but not send emails.

I have configured Postfix using [How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-22-04) tutorial from DigitalOcean.

`sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log` gives:

```
Dec 31 11:26:01 example postfix/smtp[9961]: 58A39D25A: to=<opendkim@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for example.com loops back to myself)
Dec 31 11:26:01 example postfix/smtp[8787]: 58103D252: to=<vmail@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for example.com loops back to myself)
Dec 31 11:26:01 example postfix/smtp[9593]: 576CAD23A: to=<root@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for example.com loops back to myself)
Dec 31 11:26:01 example postfix/qmgr[5301]: 58A39D25A: removed
Dec 31 11:26:01 example postfix/qmgr[5301]: 58103D252: removed
Dec 31 11:26:01 example postfix/qmgr[5301]: 576CAD23A: removed
Dec 31 11:26:25 example postfix/smtp[7272]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.150.26]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 31 11:26:44 example postfix/pickup[9439]: 69CE6D23E: uid=1001 from=<founder@example.com>
Dec 31 11:26:44 example postfix/cleanup[8226]: 69CE6D23E: message-id=<20231231112644.pRsVV%founder@example.com>
Dec 31 11:26:44 example postfix/qmgr[5301]: 69CE6D23E: from=<founder@example.com>, size=335, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 31 11:26:55 example postfix/smtp[7272]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1b]:25: Connection timed out
Dec 31 11:26:55 example postfix/smtp[7272]: D1398D22E: to=<examplez@gmail.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=4374, delays=4223/0/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1b]:25: Connection timed out)
```

What could be the reason I cannot send email?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these have been answered several times on Server Fault... Did you Google for the errors?

- `mail for example.com loops back to myself`

  This error is self-explanatory: the MX records of the `example.com` points back to the Postfix server, but the server is not configured to accept mail for the domain.

  Related questions:

  - [mail loops back to myself | postfix](https://serverfault.com/q/69991/274176)
- `25: Connection timed out`

  It is common to block outbound port `25/tcp` on hosts that are not supposed to be sending email. You should ask the ISP of the server whether it is possible to open it.

  Related questions:

  - [Many ISP's is block port 25, how do I choose an alternative port?](https://serverfault.com/q/452653/274176)
  - [Outgoing SMTP Blocked](https://serverfault.com/q/564096/274176)
  - [Postfix - Connection timed out on port 2525](https://serverfault.com/q/1063099/274176)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm using Dovecot to act as my IMAP server with POSTFIX. The error is more specific now to be a login problem to Dovecot, The error returned is: dovecot[211047]: lmtp(212559): Error: lmtp-server: conn unix:pid=212562,uid=113 [5]: rcpt opendkim@xxx.com Failed to initialize user: Mail access for users with UID 114 not permitted (see first_valid_uid in config file, uid from userdb lookup)

Comment: That is entirely unrelated error. If you have a new problem, ask another question.