# Dovecot - rcpt opendkim@example.com: Failed to initialize user

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

I have an SMTP server:

- Dovecot as its IMAP server
- Postfix as its MTA
- OpenDKIM to sign the emails.

When I send mail it throws this error:

`Jan 01 10:46:01 example.com dovecot[211047]: lmtp(219823): Error: lmtp-server: conn unix:pid=219911,uid=113 [10]: rcpt opendkim@example.com: Failed to initialize user: Mail access for users with UID 114 not permitted (see first_valid_uid in config file, uid from userdb lookup).`

I should note that I can connect to my server to read emails, but cannot send. This relates to a previous question: [Postfix doesn't send mail; example.com loops back to myself & Connection timed out](https://serverfault.com/q/1150694/274176)

Comment: It says `see first_valid_uid in config file, uid from userdb lookup`; what's there?

Comment: In /etc/opendkim.conf : 
UserID                  opendkim
UMask                   007

Comment: This is a message from Dovecot `dovecot[211047]`; `opendkim.conf` is unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work on your diagnostic skills as the error message directly points to the related configuration and tells what might be wrong with it.

- `dovecot[211047]`

  This part tells that the log message is from the `dovecot` process; there is probably something wrong with Dovecot's configuration.
- `Mail access for users with UID 114 not permitted`

  For some reason, user with UID `114` is not allowed to login to Dovecot. That is a system user: you can use command `id 114` to show which user it is to decide whether it should be able to login to Dovecot or not.
- `(see first_valid_uid in config file, uid from userdb lookup)`

  Here it tells what to look for. The related [System users used by Dovecot configuration](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/system_users_used_by_dovecot/#uids) says:

  > By default Dovecot allows users to log in only with UID numbers `500` and above. This check tries to make sure that no-one can ever log in as daemons or other system users. If you’re using an UID lower than `500`, you’ll need to change the `first_valid_uid` setting.

  On a fresh installation of `dovecot-imapd` on Ubuntu 22.04:

  ```
  $ doveconf -a | grep "first_valid_uid"
  first_valid_uid = 500
  ```

  As a default setting it is commented out in configuration files:

  ```
  $ grep "first_valid_uid" /etc/dovecot/conf.d/*.conf
  /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:# be done even if first_valid_uid is set to 0.
  /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:#first_valid_uid = 500
  ```

  Edit `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` by uncommenting the line add set is as required, e.g.,

  ```
  first_valid_uid = 114
  ```

  Keep in mind that this allows all system users with UID `114` and above to login to Dovecot. [User Databases](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/user_databases_userdb/) could be used for more fine-graded configuration.

Comment: The above error stopped when I did @Esa Jokinaon solution.